# Populate a list in a UIPickerView in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uipickerview

I have a list saved in an object. I want to populate the same list in `UIPickerView` in Xamarin iOS but it is showing an error of tycasting.

the list is coming from a webservice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at the samples from Xamarin? 
This [one](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/MonoCatalog-MonoDevelop) in particular is exactly what you are looking for, below is a snippet of code that sets up a custom UIPickerView.

Looks like you need to create a Model that is a subclass of UIPickerViewModel, [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIPickerViewModel/) is the Docs from Xamarin on this class

```
void CreatePicker ()
    {
        //
        // Empty is used, since UIPickerViews have auto-sizing,
        // all that is required is the origin
        //
        myPickerView = new UIPickerView (CGRect.Empty){
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
            ShowSelectionIndicator = true,
            Model = new PeopleModel (this),
            BackgroundColor = backgroundColor,
            Hidden = true
        };
        // Now update it:
        myPickerView.Frame = PickerFrameWithSize (myPickerView.SizeThatFits (CGSize.Empty));
        View.AddSubview (myPickerView);
    }

    public class PeopleModel : UIPickerViewModel {
        static string [] names = new string [] {
            "Brian Kernighan",
            "Dennis Ritchie",
            "Ken Thompson",
            "Kirk McKusick",
            "Rob Pike",
            "Dave Presotto",
            "Steve Johnson"
        };

        PickerViewController pvc;
        public PeopleModel (PickerViewController pvc) {
            this.pvc = pvc;
        }

        public override nint GetComponentCount (UIPickerView v)
        {
            return 2;
        }

        public override nint GetRowsInComponent (UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
        {
            return names.Length;
        }

        public override string GetTitle (UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
        {
            if (component == 0)
                return names [row];
            else
                return row.ToString ();
        }

        public override void Selected (UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
        {
            pvc.label.Text = String.Format ("{0} - {1}",
                            names [picker.SelectedRowInComponent (0)],
                            picker.SelectedRowInComponent (1));
        }

        public override nfloat GetComponentWidth (UIPickerView picker, nint component)
        {
            if (component == 0)
                return 240f;
            else
                return 40f;
        }

        public override nfloat GetRowHeight (UIPickerView picker, nint component)
        {
            return 40f;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did any of this help you? did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Added a blog post about setting up a Picker, if it helps. https://medium.com/@casseykeating/uipickerview-xamarin-ios-a9f62c9a0138